# Error with C# lambda expression which includes generic type field comparison - Unity/Mono

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, mono

I'm trying to implement an extendable class for accessing a database in my Unity game. Models will be used throughout the game, which can be "fetched". This method is part of the base class of `Model<T>` where T is a schema type that matches the database.
Because I have access to T, I can query on the schema using lambda.

Unfortunately, when I try this and the lambda expression is built, I run into a runtime error:

```
ArgumentException: The field handle and the type handle are incompatible.
System.Reflection.FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle (RuntimeFieldHandle handle, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringType) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/FieldInfo.cs:171)
ExpressionObject`1[IDObject].expression (Int32 id) (at Assets/Scripts/ELB/Test/ExistingDBScript.cs:24)
ExistingDBScript.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/ELB/Test/ExistingDBScript.cs:35)
```

I've ruled out the database connector itself as the issue, and come up with the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

Definitions:

```
public class IDObject {
    public int id;
}

public class ExpressionObject<T> where T : IDObject {

    public void expression() {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => x.id == 0;
    }

    public void expression(int id) {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => x.id == id;
    }
}
```

Instance:

```
ExpressionObject<IDObject> example = new ExpressionObject<IDObject>();
example.expression();
example.expression(2352);
```

The first call to the parameterless expression function executes fine and is error free, however the second one throws the error above.

I have also tried wrapping x in a function when accessing the id as such, which results in the same issue.

```
int idGetter(T ss) {
    return ss.id;
}

public void expression(int id) {
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => idGetter(x) == id;
}
```

Finally, I made the call a `Func<T, bool>` rather than `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` which resulted in no errors. Unfortunately, I need an `Expression` to pass to the database library that I use, and it also doesn't fix the original issue.

Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: Fixed typo

Edit: This actually works when the expression function has a generic type.

```
public void expression<S>(int id) where S : IDObject {
    Expression<Func<S, bool>> expr = x => x.id == id;
}

example.expression<IDObject>(2352);
```

This is actually identical to what I had originally, and refactored out. I don't want the caller of something() to care about the `<T>` that the class is using.

Here's an example which can be copied into unity. It's very similar to the example provided. Just drag it onto something and play.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System;

public class IDObject {
    public int id;
}

public class ExpressionObject<T> where T : IDObject {

    public void expression() {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => x.id == 0;
    }

    public void expression<S>(int id) where S : IDObject {
        Expression<Func<S, bool>> expr = x => x.id == id;
    }

    public void expression(int id) {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => x.id == id;
    }

}

public class ExtendedExpression : ExpressionObject<IDObject> {

    // This is the workaround
    public void expressionExt(int id) {
        expression<IDObject>(id);
    }

}


public class ExistingDBScript : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        ExtendedExpression example = new ExtendedExpression();
        // This works
        example.expression();
        // This also works
        example.expressionExt(2352);

        ExpressionObject<IDObject> example2 = new ExpressionObject<IDObject>();
        // This works
        example2.expression();
        // This does not work
        example2.expression(2352);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, read or write a property or field in one of your classes using an expression (your example is a bit misleading) ?

Comment: The expression is going to be used to read an "IDObject" table from a database. When i fetch, i want to be able to pass an ID, and it will return the correct row (or technically rows) which matches the ID. I've tried it with a non-generic type (i.e IdObject instead of T), and it works fine. What it's used for is outside the scope of the question, though. I'm just instantiating an instance of an expression, and it's failing. I want to know why.

Comment: @Aybe, I've edited the OP due to a typo which may have confused you, and also added an example of a modified, but working version. That isn't what I want but may highlight an issue which i may not have noticed.

Otherwise it seems like a mono bug...

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what you're trying to achieve because your question is not that clear :) I think you are looking for a `Predicate` though, take a look at my answer see if it gives you a hint, or fix your question :)

Comment: The code under Definitions and Instance runs fine for me, though I tried under .NET rather than Mono. Perhaps this is a bug in Mono?

Comment: @Abion47 Could be, I've asked OP to provide a complete example reproducing the error case, because here it runs fine too.

Comment: @Aybe I've added an example to the OP.

Comment: I have tested your example in Unity 5.5.0b6 and no errors occur (makes sense because nothing is being evaluated). This is a beta version but there's no reason why it would fail on an non-beta one. There is an idiom saying that Unity can fail when file name does not equal class name, i.e. is your file name called ExistingDBScript.cs ? Other than that I'm sorry I won't be able to help you out as things here are working as expected and not producing any error.

Comment: @Aybe I updated to the latest stable version of Unity (5.4) and running into a different issue:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1091794/gray-screen-when-trying-to-open-unity.html (So I can't make a new project)
Opening and running the existing project ends up with the same error. I know unity can fail when class names aren't the same as filenames, but that throws a different error. They are the same in this case.

Comment: @aybe Just updated now to 5.5 b7 and it seems to be fine. I looks like a bug in an old version of mono then

Comment: Alright, cool !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in old versions of Mono. Updating to a beta version of Unity (5.5 b7) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**In your second code block:**

```
public void expression(int id) {
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => x.id == id;
}
```

Will invariably fail because there is no equality comparison possible between `T` and `int`, now there might be [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) allowing you to write it even though it'll fail at runtime.

**To remove that dependency to `int`, you could use a generic predicate:**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    // checks if a property equals something, generic way
    public static bool IsEqualTo<T, TValue>(this T source, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression,
        Predicate<TValue> predicate)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("expression");

        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("expression");

        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(source);
        var value1 = (TValue) value;
        var b = predicate(value1);
        return b;
    }
}

internal class Demo
{
    private static void Test()
    {
        var data = new MyData();

        var b1 = data.IsEqualTo(s => s.Valid, t => t == false);
        var b2 = data.IsEqualTo(s => s.Number, t => t == 1234);
    }

    private struct MyData
    {
        public bool Valid { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is just an example for reading and comparing, it can be augmented for writing a value etc ...

Comment: The  problem is that there is a comparison possible between T(.id) and int.

Comment: (I Shouldn't press enter early...)  
The "where" in the class means that T should be an instance of IDObject, which has a property id of type int. That means that any T should have the property id and be comparable to any other integer. In case i'm missing anything, could you answer the question - why does the original example fail (the one you quoted) and the new example that I added (where the generic is defined by the function rather than the class) pass?

Comment: OP isn't comparing `T` and `int`. The comparison is between `T.id` and `id`, both of which are of type `int`, and the where clause on the class guarantees that `T` will have a field `id` of type `int`.

Comment: @AlasdairHurst Pasting the first example in Unity here does not cause an error (because it is not evaluated). Is the latest version in Unity ? There might be a bug in your version if it's not. For us to further help you out you should post a `Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example` -> a `MonoBehaviour` we can paste and work upon.

Comment: @Aybe added the example you asked for. I'm using unity 5.2.3f1 which isn't the latest version. I will try with a newer version and get back to you.